# Cannot create new record in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to migrate from Rails 3 to Rails 4.  I have no idea why, but when I am trying to create new record I get the error message:

```
2 errors prohibited this group from being saved:
    Name can't be blank
    Tags can't be blank
```

Here is a controller code:

```
  def create
    @user = UserData.find_by_login(session[:cuser])
    @group = @user.groups.new(params[:group])


    puts "======================="
    p @user
    p params
    p params[:group]
    p @group
    p "========"
    p @user.groups

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@group, :notice => 'Group was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @group, :status => :created, :location => @group }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @group.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is a console log:

```
=======================
```

As I see we have @user variable inizialized:

```
#<UserData id: 1, login: "demas", hashed_password: "e55105f41cd0391b440176a1cd5b14c2732410ca", salt: "xnqKXtOgwO", created_at: "2014-02-17 06:18:08", updated_at: "2014-02-17 06:18:08", last_login: "2014-02-16 20:00:00", login_count: 1, admin: 0>
```

I have group in the parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2qxvqJh0nrJiZt+7xvI0lZjA83Z+hw/GKzwrNlqEh44=", "group"=>{"name"=>"112", "tags"=>"2", "stop_tags"=>"", "download_on_refresh"=>"0", "site_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Group", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"groups"}
{"name"=>"112", "tags"=>"2", "stop_tags"=>"", "download_on_refresh"=>"0", "site_id"=>"1"}
```

But when I call @user.groups.new() I get empty group:

```
#<Group id: nil, name: nil, tags: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_data_id: 1, site_id: nil, stop_tags: nil, position: nil, last_sync: nil, download_on_refresh: nil>
```

I have checked @user.groups and as I see the relations works fine:

```
"========"
  Group Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."user_data_id" = ?  [["user_data_id", 1]]
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Group id: nil, name: nil, tags: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_data_id: 1, site_id: nil, stop_tags: nil, position: nil, last_sync: nil, download_on_refresh: nil>]>
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

Why @user.groups.new() don't create new record ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to create new record then shouldn't you use  `@user.groups.build` ?

Comment: If this is Rails 4, you should be using strong_parameters to whitelist your params before passing them to the model.

Comment: @shiva `@group = @user.groups.new(params[:group])` is identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails has implemented 'Strong parameters', hence directly using params[:group] to create a model will not work. You need to permit the controller to accept these parameter for model creation.

**Your code:**

```
def create
    @user = UserData.find_by_login(session[:cuser])
    @group = @user.groups.new(params[:group])  
    .
    .
end
```

**Possible solution:**

```
def create
    @user = UserData.find_by_login(session[:cuser])
    @group = @user.groups.new(group_post_params)
    .
    .
end

private
    def group_post_params
        params.require(:group).permit(:name, :tags, etc, etc)
    end
```

Comment: Does 'group_post_params' must be controller method ?

Comment: @demas It's in the same place as `create` method, so yes.